# How difficult is to develop a text editor in windows?

Tags: text, editor

How difficult is to develop a text editor in windows?

edit: something like this for a target: http://intype.info/home/index.php

Comment: It's trivial if you want a notepad clone, very complex if you want a new Visual Studio. (That goes for other OSes/environments.) Could you clarify what you mean by editor?

Comment: http://download.tuxfamily.org/notepadplus/5.8.7/npp.5.8.7.src.7z

Comment: @Mat noting like visualstudio, just something like a notepad++ clone with its core features like tabbed UI etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what tools you use. To develop something offering basic functionality (like Notepad) using C# and WPF or Windows Forms (or VB if that's your poison) would be pretty easy if you knew the language and the API well. Doing something similar with Python, Ruby, or something else and Tk, GTK, Qt, etc. wouldn't be terribly hard either. Same goes for Java and AWT or Swing. Any graphics toolkit with a high level language is going to give you most of the scaffolding that all you really need to do is define the layout and add some logic (opening files, saving, etc.) Developing with C or C++ (unmanaged) and the Win32 API would be much more difficult, but still relatively simple.

You could probably put together a working Notepad clone rather quickly. It gets harder as you add features. I know that with my language and toolkit of choice (Python  + Tkinter) I could probably do a feature for feature clone of Notepad in a few hours, right down to appearance and UI.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Is it possible to write one in using web technologies(JavaScript and HTML)? Would it be responsive/fast enough for something like a notepad++ clone?

Comment: @RubyDosa you definitely could. Javascript can be quite fast, and having everything on the web makes syntax highlighting and UI easier. For example, see [jsvi](http://gpl.internetconnection.net/vi/). Moreover, text editors aren't too resource hungry (emacs, which is the most intense of them all, uses about 16M memory and uses almost no CPU).

Comment: Are there libraries/tools I can use to develop it for windows?

Comment: @RubyDosa if you're doing it in Javascript and HTML, no. Your app would, in that case, be OS-independent. If you want to write it as a desktop app, look into Windows Presentation Foundation.

Comment: Yep, multi-platform is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what sort of text editor you want. For a really simple editor, you can just host an EDIT control (or RICHTEXT control), in which case you have a working editor in well under an hour. If you want to write a full-blown programmer's editor, you'd probably want to measure the time in months or years instead of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy actually:

- use whatever GUI toolkit you want
- add a multi line textbox control
- add load/save options
- compile/build/link
- and you just made a poor man's notepad :)

Now seriously, what do mean with a text editor? What kind of features are you looking for? Do want something simple like notepad, something totally awesome like notepad++, or something enormous like word?

Comment: Something like a notepad++, maybe for a OSS hobby project ;)